# Append to python parameter when type is unknown

Tags: python

I have Python v2.7.

I want to create a function which will accept `None`, a `str` or a `list`. I need to append something to the parameter so I've created a helper function as follows:

```
def _append_or_set(x, to_append):
    if x is None:
        return to_append
    if type(x) is str:
        return [x, to_append]
    if type(x) is list:
        x.append(to_append)
        return x
```

(Obviously this is not great programming, and there's no error handling etc. but it's just for illustration.)

But knowing Python, there is already a neat way of doing this. What is it?

#### Background on why I'm doing this

I'm doing this because I want to filter a dataset. The caller passes either None (i.e. return all the rows) or a string (just rows matching this value) or a list (rows matching *any* of these values)

Regardless of what the caller asks for, I always need to include rows containing `foo` at the very least. So I do:

```
def _filter_data(filter_by):
    filter_by = _append_or_set(filter_by, 'foo')
    return do_my_filtering(filter_by)
```

Comment: Its a little unclear why you're approaching the problem this way.  Could you edit to give a little insight into why you've done what you've done?

Comment: I would say your code is fine, I would just do `return [to_append]` when x is `None` to make the function always return a list for uniformity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible that I still may not be understanding what you want, but I think this will work:

```
>>> def _append_or_set(x, to_append):
...     try:
...         x.append(to_append)
...     except AttributeError:
...         if x:
...             x = [x, to_append]
...         else:
...             x = to_append
...     finally:
...         return x
...
>>> _append_or_set([5,3,4], 6)
[5, 3, 4, 6]
>>> _append_or_set("this is x,", "this is appended")
['this is x,', 'this is appended']
>>> _append_or_set(None, "hello")
'hello'
```

By using `try...except...finally` you can avoid explicit type checking which is generally considered bad practice.

The first `try` assumes `x` is a list.  It isn't (if `x.append()` breaks), then it must be a string, or `None`. A simple `if` will determine which it is.

Comment: This is my favourite answer so far, as I learned some good practice tips in the process!

Comment: @LondonRob, Duck typing is one of the best features of Python! Is there anything I can improve on?

Answer (score 2):

While your function would work fine (except that you should probably use `isinstance` and `elif`s), I do see a problem with it, and that is that it does not really have a consistent interface. Assuming that `to_append` is a string, there are three different situations:

1. `None` is passed, the function returns a string.
2. A string is passed, the function returns a 2-element list.
3. A list is passed, the function appends to the list and returns it. The original passed list *is also changed* (meaning a possible side effect to the parameter).

Instead, you should try to keep the interface consistent. For example, always return a list and don’t touch the parameter itself:

```
def _append_or_set(x, to_append):
    if x is None:
        return [to_append]
    elif isinstance(x, (list, tuple, set)): # also accept tuples and sets
        return list(x) + [to_append]
    else:
        # assume that anything else is fine as the first element
        return [x, to_append]
```

Comment: Thanks @poke. Just amazed there's no sugary way to do this as it must be a relatively normal use case.

Comment: @LondonRob Normally you'll use a protocol to have common functionality for a similar group of types and then wrap it in a try-except block for fallthrough behavior, though the efficiency can vary depending on how often certain types are passed to your function (lots of strings or `None`s will cause the exception-catching method to run a bit slower than if `list`s are more common, as the method avoids the pre-check but incurs a bit of penalty when it fails. That sort of "ask for forgiveness rather than permission" is generally considered a more Pythonic style, though).

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.4 adds a `singledispatch` decorator to the `functools` module, which lets you use a bit more of a generic programming style:

```
@singledispatch
def append_or_set(x, to_append):
    raise RuntimeError("Unregistered type")

# This one isn't strictly necessary; you could just have the default behavior
# in the original function be to return the value to append if no other types
# will be supplied.
@append_or_set.register(type(None))
def append_or_set(x, to_append):
    return to_append


@append_or_set.register(str)
def append_or_set(x, to_append):
    return [x, to_append]

@append_or_set.register(list)
def append_or_set(x, to_append):
    x.append(to_append)
    return x
```

You can find more information [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch), but the most relevant point is one not listed there: the implementation of `functools.singledispatch` is all Python, so even though you're using Python 2.7 you can backport the necessary code from Python 3.4's version of `functools.py` and use that. It shouldn't be too much trouble as the functions associated with `singledispatch` don't appear to use any functionality from Python 3 that is significantly different from that usable in 2.7 even without `__future__` imports (though I may well be wrong on that as I haven't tested it).

Also, as others have said, it may be a good idea to make the return values more consistent and, unless desired, avoid mutating arguments, e.g. `return to_append` would become `return [to_append]` and `x.append(to_append);return x` would become `return x + [to_append]`.